# Remove detected resolutions

Tags: display, monitors, resolution, display-settings, edid

There are many articles about how to add undetected resolutions. My problem is the opposite:

*gnome-control-center* shows many resolutions I won't ever use.

Here is my list with 33 entries on a 3840x2160 monitor:
[image: Example 3840x2160 screen]

**How to clean up this list** (per monitor) **and only keep these 2 entries?**

- 3840x2160 (native resolution)
- 1920x1080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatically detected modes cannot be deleted.

Ping developers: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/issues/353

You can try creating and using a custom EDID file for your monitor:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Kernel_mode_setting#Forcing_modes_and_EDID

Comment: EDID provides the native resolution. In my case this is 3840x2160@60Hz and @50Hz (retrieved by `edid-decode /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/edid`). If I now limit this to a lower resolution by generating an EDID binary with e.g. 1920x1080, then I won't be able to use the true native 4k anymore. At least this is my understanding. / I also updated my question.